# How to handle UITapGestureRecognizer in a subview?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a viewcontroller (vc1) in which I added another viewcontroller (vc2) as a subview. An UITapGestureRecognizer is triggered when you tap on a view (tappingView) contained in the subview (vc2). I would like to handle this tap inside the subview controller (vc2), and not from the first viewcontroller (vc1)... but it keeps crashing when I click on my view.

Here is the hierarchy sum up :

-vc1
--vc2
---tappingView

And here is a sample of code :

ViewController1 (viewDidLoad):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    [[self view] addSubview:[vc2 view]];
}
```

ViewController2 (viewDidLoad):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIView *tappingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60.0, 80.0)];
    [[self view] addSubview:tappingView];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognize = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureRecognizer:)];
    [tappingView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognize];
}
```

ViewController2 (singleTapeGestureRecognizer:) :

```
- (void)singleTapGestureRecognizer:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Tap gesture");
}
```

When I click in my view (tappingView), I keep getting a crash (BAD_ACCESS).

Anyone have an idea why ?

Comment: use - (void)singleTapGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender instead of  - (void)singleTapGestureRecognizer:(id)sender. As it must have UIGestureREcognizer instead of id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this block

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    [[self view] addSubview:[vc2 view]];
}
```

your `ViewController2` is **not** retained (`addSubview` only retains the view, not the view controller).

To fix it, declare `vc2` as a `strong` property, instead of a variable.

```
self.vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
```

Or better, as someone suggested, add `vc2` as a child view controller.

Comment: Solved my problem. Working late doesn't suit me sometimes... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't just add another view controller's view to your view -- you should make that controller a childViewController of vc1. Change the viewDidLoad in vc1 to this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:vc2];
    [vc2 didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [[self view] addSubview:[vc2 view]];
}
```

It's not clear why you're doing it this way in the first place. Why not present vc2 as a modal view controller instead?

Comment: It'right, only you add the controller as a child controller, the tap can be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Targets of `UITapGestureRecognizer` take the `UIGestureRecognizer` argument, not `id`. I.e.:

```
- (void)singleTapGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
  NSLog(@"Tap gesture");
}
```

Further, you're setting frames in `viewDidLoad`, which you should do in `viewWillAppear:` instead.

Comment: While it's true that it's better to properly type the argument to action methods, it wouldn't cause this error.

Answer (score -1):

use below code

```
- (void)singleTapGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
```

instead of

```
- (void)singleTapGestureRecognizer:(id)sender.
```

As it must have UIGestureREcognizer instead of id.`

Comment: It doesn't matter. If `id` is used, `sender` is simply cast from `UIGestureRecognizer*` (or whatever the real class is) to `id`.